# Join paths in shape in Sketchapp

Tags: vector, sketch-app

I'm trying to make simple icons to use with Fontello.  When I export what I've made as an svg and try importing it to fontello, it won't import it properly and it complains:

"If image looks not as expected please convert to compound path manualy. Skipped tags and attributes: stroke,stroke-width,fill,fill-rule"

My question then:  how do I join all these paths? Especially the ones that aren't even touching?

Thanks!

Update: I'm unable to bring shapes from Sketch to Icomoon either. The svg file is [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/984813/download-arrow.svg) for anyone who wants to have a look at what I'm doing. The Sketch file is [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/984813/download%20icon.sketch).

[image: sketch icon]

Comment: Have you tried to drag "Path 3" into "Path 1" group, so that all of the 3 layers are within "Path 1"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty sure you can simply ignore the Fontello error. Works fine when I give it a go.

[image]

[image]

Feel free to download the Sketch & SVG file that I used here http://ge.tt/8LyJbb12 (it also includes the resulting Fontello zip file)

**UPDATE**: just tried it with your Sketch file, all you have to do is convert the lines to strokes: Layer / Paths / Vectorize Stroke, and you're set!

Comment: Hummmm Yeah. Your version works perfectly. How did you make the shape? It looks like it isn't a group, but yet it's all "grouped" together. I'd love to get some details from you!

Comment: Ah sorry, didn't see this comment before I updated my answer, but all you have to do is convert the lines to strokes: Layer / Paths / Vectorize Stroke.

Grouping (or placing it on an Artboard as I did) doesn't really matter. It should work now.

Comment: Ack. Still wont work for me. Did you join paths or something first?

Comment: Could you upload your sketch file again (sorry I deleted it a bit too quick) and I'll describe exactly what I did.

Comment: Sure!  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/984813/terrys%20terrible%20arrow.sketch Really appreciate the help!

Comment: I must be doing something wrong. I just tried to export a square. A simple square, as an svg and that wasn't recognized in Fontello either.

Comment: Just downloaded your file.

I hit CTRL+A (select all) followed by Layer / Paths / Vectorize Strokes. http://i.imgur.com/lMcIGqd.jpg Exporting this to SVG worked fine in Fontello. 

Here's how I export: Select the "terry's terrible arrow" Artboard, select "Make Exportable" http://i.imgur.com/84Cr1bX.png (bottom right) and select 1x SVG followed by clicking the "Export terry's terrible..." button http://i.imgur.com/ZsnXsVx.png (bottom right).

Comment: Weirrrrd. It worked this time. I can't see how I was doing anything different, but it did work this tiem. Thanks so much for the help. I really really appreciate it.

Comment: No problem. Sketch can be a bit finicky at times. But is pretty powerful, I'm still learning new things every day. Glad to share some knowledge.